# Send ETH Transaction based on price

Tags: events, oracles

I'd like to be able to execute an ETH transaction on chain based on a change in price of an asset.  This seems like a job for an Oracle, but aside from an app that's not on chain that watches for price changes, I'm not sure how to go about doing this the "block chain way."

Comment: Are you looking to deploy a smart contract that can do this? There is a pretty easy way to do this with a chainlink data feed (yes, an oracle)

Comment: @PatrickCollins So, a chainlink data feed can make the contract run a transaction?  Is there a link to some example for this?

Comment: Yes. The logic would go `if price change -> then send transaction`. Is this what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

The "blockchain way" you refer to is unfeasible from a technical & cost perspective.

Contract execution is triggered by external calls to the contract's functions; therefore, there is no straightforward way to *listen* for events within the contract.

Even if you could listen for events inside a contract, such as a price variant, this would represent a permanent cost in terms of gas fees. Moreover, since these costs are accumulated per transaction, in the end the initial transaction that initiated the contract listening would reach the gas limit and would eventually fail.

The only way to proceed is by using external sources (aka. Oracles) that will call your contract when there is a price difference. *Chainlink* is giving you this feature with curated data, but using it is not cheap. You can build your own Oracle and call your contract, but you need to consider potential attacks to this Oracle, so data arriving to your contract could be tampered.